# Trying to Output Math.Random(); Unsuccessfully

Tags: javascript, html, output

I'm using JSBin.com to test this simple code, for fun, but I can't seem to get it to output anything in the "Output" window on the site... is this just a limitation of the site or am I missing something completely obvious?

Here's my HTML-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Math.Random</title>
  </head>

  <body onLoad "findRandom();">
    <p id="getRandom"> </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my JS-

```
function findRandom() 
{
  document.getElementById("getRandom").innerHTML =  Math.random();
}
```

Comment: `onLoad "findRandom();"`? Try `onload="findRandom();"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing an equal sign maybe

```
<body onLoad="findRandom();">
```

Comment: Ugh, I knew it was something completely obvious. Thank you.